# HDMI keeps cutting out

Tags: hdmi

On one end I have a desktop, a mini-PC or a macbook; in the middle I have 3 HDMI cables (2 round and a flat); on the other end I have either a Philips TV or a HP monitor. Any combination of these keeps cutting out. Not very bad but several times every day and the black display only lasts 1 - 2 seconds. The mini-PC, the desktop and the HP monitor has VGA, using that the problem does not appear. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/154539/593573) suggests there may be some interference problem, but how would I find it? I'm in a home office situation in a 40 years old building, could some sort of a powergrid problem cause this? If so, how can I test and remedy it? In my not-covid-times office the mini-PC or macbook, the flat HDMI cable and a different monitor did not cut out so it's probably a location specific problem.